# Latest Post SoundCloud?

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how I can find the latest songs per genre on **SoundCloud** after looking over their **API** I have not had any luck finding out how to achieve this or if it is even possible.

[API Documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference).

Can someone help me find the correct part of the reference to achieve this?
Trying to achieve this with **PHP**.

Comment: You can use the `created_at` attribute to get all from `today` and then order them by their respective `ids`, however there's no guarantee it'll only be the most recent, just todays, which is a limitation of the SC api.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy looking at it now, and it seems like this might be the only option I have :\